# Access vue component getter in tupescript mixin error (TS2339)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, mixins

i have this:

```
import {Component, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({})
export default class MyMixin extends Vue {
scrollToTop(): void {
        let scrollingWrapper: any = (this.$refs[this.activeTab] as Vue).$refs['scrolling-wrapper'];
        ...
    }
}
```

then

```
export default class MyModal extends MyMixin {
        get activeTab(): string {
            return myStore.activeTab;
        }
}
```

Mixin calls component's getter and everything works fine, but i get this message TS2339: Property `activeTab` does not exist on type 'MyMixin'.

Comment: Have you defined ```activeTab```  in ```MyMixin``` class ?

Comment: No, i nave not. I am calling this.$refs without additional definitions.

Comment: What is the version of typescript you are using?

Comment: Version of typescript is 3.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining it here

```
import {Component, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({})
export default class MyMixin extends Vue {

activeTab: any;
scrollToTop(): void {
        let scrollingWrapper: any = (this.$refs[**this.activeTab**] as Vue).$refs['scrolling-wrapper'];
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: There are few components with few stores so activeTab has quite dynamic behavior and cannot be defined once for good.

Comment: can you try calling ```scrollingWrapper``` instead of  ```activeTab```

Comment: Probably not, as you can see - i define scrollingWrapper depending on current activeTab.

Answer (score 0):

It is a poor solution, but i'm not able to find another. Casted this to any before method call.

```
let scrollingWrapper: any = (this.$refs[(this as any).activeTab] as Vue).$refs['scrolling-wrapper'];
```

Thanks to everyone.